# SSIS Package Installation Error

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am getting this error when I try to install my package on the server

```
Loading the package "E:\SomeFolder\SomePackage.dtsx".
Error: Could not save the package "E:\SomeFolder\SomePackage.dtsx" to SQL Server "(local)". 
Exception details: Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DtsRuntimeException: The package failed to load due to error 0xC0011008 "Error loading from XML. No further detailed error information can be specified for this problem because no Events object was passed where detailed error information can be stored.". This occurs when CPackage::LoadFromXML fails.
 ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0xC0011008): The package failed to load due to error 0xC0011008 "Error loading from XML. No further detailed error information can be specified for this problem because no Events object was passed where detailed error information can be stored.". This occurs when CPackage::LoadFromXML fails.

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.ApplicationClass.LoadPackage(String FileName, Boolean loadNeutral, IDTSEvents100 pEvents)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application.LoadPackage(String fileName, IDTSEvents events, Boolean loadNeutral)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application.LoadPackage(String fileName, IDTSEvents events, Boolean loadNeutral)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application.LoadPackage(String fileName, IDTSEvents events)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Deployment.DtsInstaller.SavePackageToSqlServer(WizardInputs wizardInputs, String packagePassword, Boolean bUseSeverEncryption, String serverName, String userName, String password, String packageFilePath, List`1 configFileNames, String packagePath)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Deployment.DtsInstaller.InstallPackagesToSqlServer(WizardInputs wizardInputs)
```

What I am doing it rebuilding the SSIS project and copying the Deployment files on the server.  Once its all there I run the SSISDeploymentManifest file.

Here is a screenshot of the step by step procedure:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

This was working before but I don't know why it suddenly stopped installing?  The only changes I made are:

1. Upgraded the project to VS2010 from 2008, it runs fine on my local machine after upgrade
2. Did some minor code changes but I guess this wont affect the installation.

Now what am I doing wrong?

BTW I am installing to SQL Server 2008

Comment: did u tried opening the package and running it successfuly from VS2010?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using VS2010, you have upgraded your package to the SQL 2012 level.  You will no longer be able to load or run that package on SQL 2008.

Answer (score 1):

> > it runs fine on my local machine after upgrade

Do you mean it runs fine inside visual studio or fine inside a local SQL Server?

At a guess: you cannot import a package upgraded to VS2010 into SQL 2008.

Why don't you compare the actual XML (load the 2010 and 2008 DTSX files into a XML editor) and see how different the files are.

Comment: it runs in Visual Studio not local SQL Server instance

Comment: Compared them both and you are right, they are totally different and you gave me a good insight, +1 for you